# django the print() is not working in the terminal

Tags: python, django

I am currently doing Django project with sqlite3 with ORM method.

I am unable to debug as print() is not working in the terminal even if I put print() function in views.py.

I checked in python shell, the queryset is working.
[image]

In `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import BookBoardModel


def index(request):
    all_books = BookBoardModel.objects.all()
    print(all_books)
    for item in all_books:
        print(item.title)
    context = {'all_books': all_books}
    return render(request, 'category_books_page/index.html', context)
```

The terminal shown with warning sign and not giving print(): [image]

Due to this, the variable `all_books` are not properly rendered in the index.html which will not generate any objects in `index.html`

In    `index.html`

```
{{all_books}} It is not showing at all :(
```

[image]

In   `category_books_page.urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='bookHome'),
]
```

In `config.urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from signup_page import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('default_page.urls')),
    path('category_books_page/', include('category_books_page.urls')),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Comment: Use an actual debugger, for example use [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Also are you sure that `index` is the view your request gets routed to? Check your urlpatterns

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post for 'urls.py'. It seems fine for me. Can you please re-check?

Comment: What do you have in `default_page.urls`?

Comment: Oh My God, I was connecting into different urls in defauflt_page.urls. Thank you so much. God bless you

Answer (score 1):

You can try in template:

```
{% for book in all_books %}
    {{ book.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Try to restart runserver project

Comment: I tried in the index.html , and it gives the same error.

Comment: delete print(all_books) from views

Comment: I have deleted print(all_books) from views and re-start my server by clearing all cache in google chrome. still it is not showing

Comment: post your html template, plz

Comment: solved, thank you so much. It was not a problem with html ,but urls.py Thank you so much